# Схлопнуть внутреннюю колонку грида если нет элемента

Tags: css, css-grid

В следующем примере нижние элементы `mid-left` и `mid-right` должны поровну делить между собой пространство, оставшееся от других областей. Но если присутствует только один из них, то он должен занимать всё это пространство. Заранее неизвестно, будет ли присутствовать элемент, занимающий данную область, или нет. Поддержка `gap` НЕ требуется.

У меня получилось сделать такое только с помощью селектора `:has`. Как сделать то же самое, но без него?

Разметку менять нельзя. А то бы я `mid-left` и `mid-right` обернул в контейнер и всё бы получилось.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "l t  t  t" 2em
                 "l mt mt r" 1fr
                 "l ml mr r" 1fr / 5em 1fr 1fr 5em;
  min-height: 8em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.left      { grid-area: l;  background: antiquewhite; }
.top       { grid-area: t;  background: silver;       }
.right     { grid-area: r;  background: antiquewhite; }
.mid-top   { grid-area: mt; background: yellow;       }
.mid-left  { grid-area: ml; background: aquamarine;   }
.mid-right { grid-area: mr; background: lightsalmon;  }

section:not(:has(.mid-left)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 0 1fr 5em;
}

section:not(:has(.mid-right)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 1fr 0 5em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left takes half of space</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right takes half of space</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
</section>
```

PS: На самом деле в моей разметке есть несколько обёрток с `display: contents`, поэтому весьма вероятно, что решения, основанные на порядке элементов мне не подойдут. Тем не менее, мне кажется эти решения тоже полезны в вопросе (поскольку `display: contents` довольно редко используется, да и может меня на какую подходящую мысль наведут).

Вообще, я не собирался добавлять такие примеры, но раз уж просят, то вот:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "l t  t  t" 2em
                 "l mt mt r" 1fr
                 "l ml mr r" 1fr / 5em 1fr 1fr 5em;
  min-height: 8em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

some-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}

.left      { grid-area: l;  background: antiquewhite; }
.top       { grid-area: t;  background: silver;       }
.right     { grid-area: r;  background: antiquewhite; }
.mid-top   { grid-area: mt; background: yellow;       }
.mid-left  { grid-area: ml; background: aquamarine;   }
.mid-right { grid-area: mr; background: lightsalmon;  }

section:not(:has(.mid-left)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 0 1fr 5em;
}

section:not(:has(.mid-right)) {
  grid-template-columns: 5em 1fr 0 5em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
  </some-wrapper>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  </some-wrapper>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  </some-wrapper>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  </some-wrapper>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
  </some-wrapper>
  
  <some-wrapper>
  </some-wrapper>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  
  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
    <div class="top">Top</div>
  </some-wrapper>

  <div class="right">Right</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>

  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
    <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  </some-wrapper>

  <some-wrapper>
    <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  </some-wrapper>

  <div class="right">Right</div>
</section>
```

[Этот вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75068602/4928642)

Answer (score 1):

- [grid-column-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start)
- [grid-column-end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end)

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "l t  t  t" 2em
                 "l mt mt r" 1fr
                 "l ml mr r" 1fr / 5em 1fr 1fr 5em;
  min-height: 8em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.left      { grid-area: l;  background: antiquewhite; }
.top       { grid-area: t;  background: silver;       }
.right     { grid-area: r;  background: antiquewhite; }
.mid-top   { grid-area: mt; background: yellow;       }
.mid-left  { grid-area: ml; background: aquamarine;   }
.mid-right { grid-area: mr; background: lightsalmon;  }

/* Если элемент последний и единственный, то задаём начальный и конечный столбец */
.mid-top + .mid-left:last-child,
.mid-top + .mid-right:last-child { 
  grid-column-start: ml;
  grid-column-end: mr;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left takes half of space</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right takes half of space</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Но мне не подойдёт из-за того, что у меня есть обёртки с `display: contents` и эти элементы не находятся на одном уровне...

Comment: Хмм... Звучит как небольшое усложнение селектора. Думаю если будет в примере, то что-нибудь получиться придумать

Comment: Я могу поставить `mid-left` в начало или в конец на верхнем уровне (непосредственным потомком `section`), но всё остальное может быть где угодно. Проверку на `:last-child` организовать не получится. На английском SO дали немного другой ответ и там можно 2 из 3 селекторов переделать, но всё равно не сходится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дополни таки примером с контэнтсами, а то действительно не совсем ясно с чем надо иметь дело... да и для контентсов это решение должно подходить вроде, если ничего не путаю... оно ж буквально апает елемент на уровень выше в иерархии(типа из племянника получается брат во всех смыслах).

Comment: @puffleeck, насколько я понял из комментария, проблема не в `display: contents`, а в том, что мы можем гарантировать положение внутри `section` только для `.mid-left`

Comment: @puffleeck, добавил примеры.

Comment: @Ein, добавил примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Решение несколько прямолинейное, основано на спанах, поэтому исключительно на рассмотрение с дальнейшими пожеланиями:

**Идея:**

Если левая колонка последняя — растягиваем, для правой делаем спан 2, но если правая идет за левой то спан оставляем 1.

```
.mid-right,
.mid-left:last-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.mid-left + .mid-right{
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "l t  t  t" 2em
                 "l mt mt r" 1fr
                 "l ml mr r" 1fr / 5em 1fr 1fr 5em;

  min-height: 8em;
}

section + section {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.left      { grid-area: l;  background: antiquewhite; }
.top       { grid-area: t;  background: silver;       }
.right     { grid-area: r;  background: antiquewhite; }
.mid-top   { grid-area: mt; background: yellow;       }
.mid-left  { grid-area: ml; background: aquamarine;   }
.mid-right { grid-area: mr; background: lightsalmon;  }

.mid-right,
.mid-left:last-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.mid-left + .mid-right{
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left takes half of space</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right takes half of space</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should take all width</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="top">Top</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  
  <div class="mid-top">Mid top</div>
  <div class="mid-left">Mid left</div>
  <div class="mid-right">Mid right should have equal width even if it has more content</div>
</section>
```